# Вывод из функции в c++

Tags: c++, функции, вывод, адрес

Всем здравствуйте, следующая проблема: 
У меня есть функция `"showArray"` она выводит случайные числа, я в `"main"` приписываю её, а как мне теперь увидеть сгенерированные числа? В `main` прописываю : `cout << showArray`; но выводит какой-то адрес,а не числа. Как сделать,чтобы числа были?

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>

    using namespace std ;
    void generateArray(int *arr,int n);
    void showArray(int *arr,int n);
    int searchMin(int *arr,int n);
    int searchMax(int *arr,int n);
    void echangeMinMax(int *arr,int index_of_min,int index_of_max);
    void sortUpArray(int *arr,int n);
    void deleteEvenElements(int *arr,int &n);
    void moveLeftElements(int *arr,int n);
    int main()
    {   
        int n;
        cin>> n;
        int *arr=new int[n]; 
        generateArray(arr,n) ;
        showArray(arr,n);
        int index_of_min=searchMin(arr,n);
        cout<<arr[index_of_min]<<endl;
        int index_of_max=searchMax(arr,n);
        cout<<arr[index_of_max]<<endl;
        echangeMinMax(arr,index_of_min, index_of_max);
        showArray(arr,n);

        delete[] arr;
        system ("pause");

        return 0;
    }

    void generateArray(int *arr,int n)
    {
        int a,b;
        cin>> a;
        cin>> b;
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
            arr [i]=rand()%(b-a+1)+a;
    }
    void showArray(int *arr,int n)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout << arr[i]<< " " ;
        cout<<endl;
    }

    int searchMin(int *arr,int n)
    {
        int index_of_min=0;
        for (int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            if ( arr [i]<arr[index_of_min])
            {
                index_of_min= i;

            }
        }

        return index_of_min;
    }

    int searchMax(int *arr,int n)
    {
        int index_of_max=0;
        for (int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            if ( arr [i]>arr[index_of_max])
            {
                index_of_max= i;

            }
        }

        return index_of_max;
    }
    void echangeMinMax(int *arr,int index_of_min,int index_of_max)
    {
        swap(arr[index_of_min],arr[index_of_max]);
    }

    void sortUpArray(int *arr,int n);
    {

        for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
            for (int j=i;j<n;i++)

            if ( arr [i]>arr[i])
            {
                swap (arr [i],arr[i]);
            }


    }
```

Comment: Вы пишете именно `cout << showArray` ? (тем самым выводите адрес функции showArray)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос странный...

```
int main()
{   
    int n;
    cin>> n;
```

Вы ввели `n`

```
    int *arr=new int[n]; 
    generateArray(arr,n) ;
```

Ввели числа `a` и `b` и заполнили массив.

```
    showArray(arr,n);
```

Вывели массив на экран.

```
    int index_of_min=searchMin(arr,n);
    cout<<arr[index_of_min]<<endl;
```

Нашли и вывели индекс минимального значения

```
    int index_of_max=searchMax(arr,n);
    cout<<arr[index_of_max]<<endl;
```

Для максимума

```
    echangeMinMax(arr,index_of_min, index_of_max);
```

Обменяли

```
    showArray(arr,n);
```

Опять вывели массив

Что вы еще хотите?

Еще раз его вывести? просто пишите, как и ранее -

```
    showArray(arr,n);
```

Запись `cout << showArray` выведет адрес функции.